# Group Concat while table joining

Tags: mysql

I am trying to concat ExpenseNumbers with a separator , where the column PK_TransID = FK_trans is the same. It surely involves group by and group_concat but somehow I cant get this working. If you need some extra information just ask.

Table structures

**Table wydatki**

```
| id_wydatku |       dokument |
|------------|----------------|
|        111 |        0070317 |
|        112 |   4642k1045917 |
|        113 |  10235k1071417 |
|        116 |   9948k2054917 |
|        119 |  10039k3071417 |
```

**Table pracownik_bank**

```
| id_transakcji |          trans_type |   price |
|---------------|---------------------|---------|
|             1 | Wypłata z bankomatu |    -300 |
|             2 | Wypłata z bankomatu |    -300 |
|             3 |      Płatność kartą |  -25.48 |
|             4 | Wypłata z bankomatu |    -500 |
|             5 |      Płatność kartą |     -94 |
|             6 |      Płatność kartą |   -3.28 |
|             7 |      Płatność kartą |     -65 |
```

**Table wydatki_bank**

```
| id_powiazania | fk_transakcji | fk_wydatku |
|---------------|---------------|------------|
|             1 |             6 |        121 |
|             2 |             9 |        115 |
|             3 |            12 |        110 |
|             4 |            15 |        118 |
|             5 |            16 |        111 |
|             6 |            16 |        112 |
|             7 |            16 |        113 |
|             8 |            16 |        116 |
|             9 |            14 |        123 |



|    PK_ | FK_trans | PK_TransID = FK_trans | FK_expense |  ExpenseNumber |
|--------|----------|-----------------------|------------|----------------|
| (null) |   (null) |                     1 |     (null) |         (null) |
| (null) |   (null) |                     2 |     (null) |         (null) |
| (null) |   (null) |                     3 |     (null) |         (null) |
| (null) |   (null) |                     4 |     (null) |         (null) |
| (null) |   (null) |                     5 |     (null) |         (null) |
|      1 |        6 |                     6 |        121 |    378cb082017 |
| (null) |   (null) |                     7 |     (null) |         (null) |
| (null) |   (null) |                     8 |     (null) |         (null) |
|      2 |        9 |                     9 |        115 |         (null) |
| (null) |   (null) |                    10 |     (null) |         (null) |
| (null) |   (null) |                    11 |     (null) |         (null) |
|      3 |       12 |                    12 |        110 |         (null) |
| (null) |   (null) |                    13 |     (null) |         (null) |
|      9 |       14 |                    14 |        123 | 22650820170301 |
|      4 |       15 |                    15 |        118 |         (null) |
|      5 |       16 |                    16 |        111 |        0070317 |
|      6 |       16 |                    16 |        112 |   4642k1045917 |
|      7 |       16 |                    16 |        113 |  10235k1071417 |
|      8 |       16 |                    16 |        116 |   9948k2054917 |
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4713/14

Desired output

```
|    PK_ | FK_trans | PK_TransID = FK_trans | FK_expense |  ExpenseNumber |
|--------|----------|-----------------------|------------|----------------|
| (null) |   (null) |                     1 |     (null) |         (null) |
| (null) |   (null) |                     2 |     (null) |         (null) |
| (null) |   (null) |                     3 |     (null) |         (null) |
| (null) |   (null) |                     4 |     (null) |         (null) |
| (null) |   (null) |                     5 |     (null) |         (null) |
|      1 |        6 |                     6 |        121 |    378cb082017 |
| (null) |   (null) |                     7 |     (null) |         (null) |
| (null) |   (null) |                     8 |     (null) |         (null) |
|      2 |        9 |                     9 |        115 |         (null) |
| (null) |   (null) |                    10 |     (null) |         (null) |
| (null) |   (null) |                    11 |     (null) |         (null) |
|      3 |       12 |                    12 |        110 |         (null) |
| (null) |   (null) |                    13 |     (null) |         (null) |
|      9 |       14 |                    14 |        123 | 22650820170301 |
|      4 |       15 |                    15 |        118 |         (null) |
|      5 |       16 |                    16 |        111 |        0070317,4642k1045917,10235k1071417,9948k2054917 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `group_concat`

```
select ...
group_concat(`wydatki`.`dokument`) as ExpenseNumber
from
join ....
group by `pracownik_bank`.id_transakcji
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4713/25)

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the example link you provided you can just group by `pracownik_bank.id_transakcji` and group_concat the desired field. 
If you want the seperator to be a comma, you dont even need to change that.

Here is the query working for your example: 
 [Query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4713/27/0)